# Mouseover/out. Прозрачность. Navbar

Tags: javascript, jquery

Помогите пожалуйста разобраться. Недавно затронул js.
После обновления страницы, наведения на navbar всё хорошо работает.

НО, после прокрутки вниз/вверх и установки изначального положения, при mouseover и mouseout на navbar пропадает прозрачность.

П.С.  Пишу первый раз на overflow, сильно не ругайтесь)

```js
window.onscroll = function() {
  var scrolled = window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop; // Получаем положение скролла

  if (scrolled <= 150) {
    // Если прокрутка есть, то делаем блок плавно прозрачным
    document.querySelector('.navbar').style.opacity = '1';

    // При наведении на блок возвращается прозрачность '1'
    $('.navbar').mouseover(function() {
      document.querySelector('.navbar').style.opacity = '1';
    })
  } else {
    // Если блок пересёк отметку, то блок стабильно прозрачный
    document.querySelector('.navbar').style.opacity = '0.5';
  };

  if (scrolled >= 150) {
    // При отведении мышки возвращается прозрачность '0.5'
    $('.navbar').mouseout(function() {
      document.querySelector('.navbar').style.opacity = '0.5';
    })
  }
};
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<section class="block-1">
  <!--  navigation start  -->
  <nav class="navbar fixed-top navbar-expand-lg py-4 px-5">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <a href="index.html" class="navbar-brand">
        <img src="img/logo.png" alt="" width="60" height="60">
      </a>

      <div class="contacts d-flex flex-column">
        <a href="tel:+79643743104" class="phone">7 / 964 / 374 31 04</a>
        <a href="mailto:uta14@gmail.com" class="mail">uta24@gmail.com</a>
      </div>

      <div class="social ml-auto">
        <a href="#" class="social-link vk"><i class="fab fa-lg fa-vk"></i></a>
        <a href="#" class="social-link facebook"><i class="fab fa-lg fa-facebook-f"></i></a>
        <a href="#" class="social-link instagram"><i class="fab fa-lg fa-instagram"></i></a>
        <a href="#" class="social-link twitter"><i class="fab fa-lg fa-twitter"></i></a>
        <a href="#" class="social-link google"><i class="fab fa-lg fa-google-plus-g"></i></a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
  <!--  navigation end  -->
```

Comment: Выложите HTML код, пожалуйста, так будет гораздо легче понять Вашу проблему! (Наглядно посмотрим)

Comment: Для css использую bootstrap 4.0.0

Answer (score 0):

Ваш код написан таким образом, что при прокрутке вы каждый раз устанавливаете обработчики на .navbar. То есть, при прокрутке выполняется много действий каждый раз, и получается какая-то каша.

Необходимо переработать примерно так:

```js
var scrolled = 0; //глобальная переменная

window.onscroll = function() {
 scrolled = window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop; //меняем значение прокрутки
 if (scrolled <= 150) {
  document.querySelector('.navbar').style.opacity = '1';
 } else {
  document.querySelector('.navbar').style.opacity = '0.5';
 }
}

$('.navbar').mouseover(function(){
 if (scrolled <= 150) {
  document.querySelector('.navbar').style.opacity = '1';
 }
});

$('.navbar').mouseout(function(){
 if (scrolled > 150) {
  document.querySelector('.navbar').style.opacity = '0.5';
 }
});
```

Я не совсем понял смысл вашей задачи, если что, доработаете мой код :)

Answer (score 0):

Вариант на jQuery и с использованием добавления\удаления класса, мне кажется так удобнее.

```js
$(window).bind('scroll', function(){ // Обработчик на скролл
  console.clear(); // Удалить
  let scrollTop = $(this).scrollTop(); // Текущая позиция скролла
  console.info(scrollTop); // Удалить
  if(scrollTop >= 150) // Если скролл больше 150px
  $('.navbar').addClass('opacity'); // Добавляем класс opacity (или любой другой)
  else // если меньше
  $('.navbar').removeClass('opacity'); // Удаляем класс
});
```

```css
body {height: 1000px; margin: 0;}
.navbar {display: block; width: 100%; height: 80px; background: #333; position: fixed; left: 0; top: 0; right: 0;}

/* Добавляем свойства к данному классу */
.navbar.opacity {opacity: .3;}
.navbar.opacity:hover {opacity: 1;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="navbar"></div>
```